# Using a variable from an other class tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, variables, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter (with python) to create a UI. How can I use the entry (which defines the user name) from one page on another page (thus another class)?
Basically, I need the user name to appear on several pages without asking the user to enter it each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make it a global variable.

```
global password
password_entry = tk.Entry(screen1, show="*", textvariable=password)
```

And then use it anywhere in your program

Answer (score 0):

I don't know do you have any database which includes the usernames. If yes you can get it from there.
if not, so you can use global variable to keep username.

```
global username
username = textbox.get("1.0","end")
```